# check user login

Tags: asp-classic, iis-7.5

I want to check a user when they login. I placed following code in an include in the CMS application but it doesn't work on IIS 7.5:

```
Function check_login(str_siteadmin,str_adminnaam)
    url = "http://www.mydomain.be/test.asp?IP=" & _
            Request.ServerVariables("LOCAL_ADDR") & _ 
            "&site=" & Request.ServerVariables("SERVER_NAME") & _
            "&siteadmin=" & str_siteadmin & _
            "&adminnaam=" & str_adminnaam &"" 
    set xmlhttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP") 
    xmlhttp.open "GET", url, false 
    xmlhttp.send "" 
    session("whoareyou")= xmlhttp.responseText 
    set xmlhttp = nothing 
end function
```

Comment: What _exactly_ "don't work"? What is supposed to happen?

Comment: Well when a client user logs in a there site i want to see that in my systempage test.asp

Comment: You're still not giving us much to go on. Are you getting any errors?  Please expand with more details.

Answer (score 0):

If your include isn't working, it's probably because Parent Paths are disabled by default in IIS 7.5. This page should help you solve the issue: http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/566/classic-asp-parent-paths-are-disabled-by-default/